# JavaScript Error in Asp.Net MVC 4 Bundling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, system.web.optimization

When I use the below Bundling in MVC 4, my App gets several JavaScript errors,such as 'jQuery undefined'

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

But when I use the below approach, my App works without JavaScript errors:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery1").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery2").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery3").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery3").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

**My Question:** what is the problem?

Comment: In debug mode, are the individual script tags added in the correct order?

Comment: Sounds like the scripts are being included in the wrong order. This answer suggests it might be the version of the Web Optimization Framework that you're using: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11995916/1043198

Comment: @AntP very thanks, i updated to Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization version 1.1.0-Beta1 now my app works correctly.

Comment: @user197508 I've posted my response as an answer :)

Comment: @AntP thanks;)  i accepted your answer with +1 vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by your scripts being included in the wrong order. You should ensure that your version of the Web Optimization Framework is up-to-date. This answer provides further details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995916/1043198

And the NuGet package:

http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

I updated Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization from version 1.0.0 to version 1.1.0-Beta1 now my app works correctly.