# MVC CDN fallback for Style Bundle

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, cdn, bundling-and-minification

Does MVC have a built in way to specify a CDN fallback for style sheets? I am trying to set up a fallback for the jQuery Mobile Structure style sheet.
Here is my code in the `RegisterBundles` method:

```
var JQMstyleSheet = new StyleBundle("~/JQMstyle", "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.min.css").Include("~/theme/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css");
JQMstyleSheet.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jQuery.mobile";
bundles.Add(JQMstyleSheet);
```

When the page renders it outputs this to the html:

```
<script>
(window.jQuery.mobile)||document.write('<script src="/JQMstyle"><\/script>');
</script>
```

When the CDN fails it doesn't dynamically add the style sheet like it does perfectly for my javascript files.
I think the problem is that it is trying to render a script, when it should be a style. Is there a different fallback property other than `CdnFallbackExpression`?

UPDATE

The Microsoft docs for `System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle` shows a `CdnFallbackExpression` as an available property, however in the description it says "Gets the script extension rendered by the `Scripts` helper class..."
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.stylebundle(v=vs.110).aspx
Is this a bug in the `System.Web.Optimization.StyleBundle` ? shouldn't that property by referencing the `Styles` helper class?

Comment: `JQMstyleSheet.CdnFallbackExpression = "window.jQuery.mobile";` why you put this?

Comment: I need the style sheet to load if the cdn fails. a check for window.jQuery.mobile will tell me if the cdn download of jquery mobile failed, then I know the style sheet cdn download most likely failed as well. I'm not sure how to check is a style sheet exists using CdnFallbackExpression.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR;**

Check out my solution which provides a StyleBundle extension method to solve the problem.

[Style Bundle Fallback](https://github.com/EmberConsultingGroup/StyleBundleFallback)

**Also**

Yes there is a bug in the Microsoft ASP.NET Optimization Framework, documented [here](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/104).

The solution is to modify the CdnFallbackExpression to be a javascript function that both checks for the stylesheet and loads the fallback, thus ignoring the bad script from the *Optimization Framework*.

There are a couple of tricky parts, especially checking for a stylesheet being loaded when it comes from another domain, like most CDN sources.

I have a solution on GitHub that you can use until the issue is fixed in the framework; however, I'd still watch out for the tricky part of determining when the stylesheet is actually loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my RegisterBundles method and it works perfectly. It automatically falls back to the local scripts and styles if the CDN fails. See if it can help.

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var jQueryCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js";
        var jQueryUICdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js";
        var jQueryUICss = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.12.1/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css";
        var jQueryValidateCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js";
        var jQueryValidateUnobtrusiveCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js";
        var modernizrCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/modernizr/modernizr-3.5.0.js";
        var respondCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js";
        var bootstrapCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.3.1/bootstrap.min.js";
        var bootstrapCSSCdn = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css";

        bundles.UseCdn = true;

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", jQueryCdn).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui", jQueryUICdn).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval", jQueryValidateCdn).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryUnobtrusive", jQueryValidateUnobtrusiveCdn));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr", modernizrCdn).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", bootstrapCdn).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/respond", respondCdn).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
        //Styles
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrapcss", bootstrapCSSCdn).Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/jqueryuicss",jQueryUICss).Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/site.css"));
        //set to true before deployment to use CDN files
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
```