# Ordering of Files within a bundle - What are the known libraries?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

In Bundling and Minification, I've known that the bundler will move around certain known file types -- so that things like jQuery will be moved to the front.

> By default, when files are bundled by ASP.NET they are sorted
>   alphabetically first, just like they are shown in Solution Explorer.
>   Then they are automatically shifted around so that known libraries and
>   their custom extensions such as jQuery, MooTools and Dojo are loaded
>   before anything else.
>   [-source](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx)

But after reading this recent question: [ASP.NET MVC - Bundle Config order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323409/asp-net-mvc-bundle-config-order), which shows how a file is getting moved by the bundler even when the user has specified the load order, I realized I didn't know **WHAT** these known file types are, or the **ORDER** they will be listed in.

I've never seen a list explaining this, and in searching, I came up with nothing.

Is there a list the shows what the known file types are and the order they will be rendered in? I would think this is something the ASP.NET team should provide developers as a resource.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Its in the doc comments for BundleCollection.AddDefaultFileOrderings:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add default file ordering for common popuular script and style libraries.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">A collection of <see cref="BundleFileSetOrdering"/> objects to populate with default values.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The purpose for applying these default file ordering values is to ensure that common libraries such as jquery are always located 
    /// at or close to the top within a bundle. These values can be all removed with <see cref="ResetAll"/>.
    /// 
    /// The default ordering values are as follows:
    /// <list type="bullet">
    ///     <item><description>reset.css</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>normalize.css</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery.js</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery-min.js</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery-*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery-ui*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery.ui*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery.unobtrusive*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>jquery.validate*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>modernizr-*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>dojo.*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>mootools-core*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>mootools-*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>prototype.js</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>prototype-*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>scriptaculous-*</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>ext.js</description></item>
    ///     <item><description>ext-*</description></item>
    /// </list>
    /// </remarks>
    public static void AddDefaultFileOrderings(IList<BundleFileSetOrdering> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("list");
        }

        BundleFileSetOrdering css = new BundleFileSetOrdering("css");
        css.Files.Add("reset.css");
        css.Files.Add("normalize.css");
        list.Add(css);

        BundleFileSetOrdering jquery = new BundleFileSetOrdering("jquery");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery.js");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery-min.js");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery-*");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery-ui*");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery.ui*");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery.unobtrusive*");
        jquery.Files.Add("jquery.validate*");
        list.Add(jquery);

        BundleFileSetOrdering mod = new BundleFileSetOrdering("modernizr");
        mod.Files.Add("modernizr-*");
        list.Add(mod);

        BundleFileSetOrdering dojo = new BundleFileSetOrdering("dojo");
        dojo.Files.Add("dojo.*");
        list.Add(dojo);

        BundleFileSetOrdering moo = new BundleFileSetOrdering("moo");
        moo.Files.Add("mootools-core*");
        moo.Files.Add("mootools-*");
        list.Add(moo);

        BundleFileSetOrdering proto = new BundleFileSetOrdering("prototype");
        proto.Files.Add("prototype.js");
        proto.Files.Add("prototype-*");
        proto.Files.Add("scriptaculous-*");
        list.Add(proto);

        BundleFileSetOrdering ext = new BundleFileSetOrdering("ext");
        ext.Files.Add("ext.js");
        ext.Files.Add("ext-*");
        list.Add(ext);
    }
```