# How can i achieve versioning for bundle.add(new ScriptBundle().includedirectory()) in BundleConfig.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create versioning for the controllers in a location using `bundle.add(new ScriptBundle().includedirectory())`, as i have been getting the answers to use `Include()` , but i need to use `IncludeDirectory().
Please suggest me some solution or references so that i can achieve , below the  BundleConfig code for my controller directory.

```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Controllers").IncludeDirectory(
                "~/App/Controllers", "*.js", true));
```

Comment: If you use include directory, be aware that the other challenge you might have is Microsoft includes JS files not in any particular order, so you might have some dependency errors...

Comment: @Brian  exactly am facing injector error when i put `System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true`.

Comment: Yeah I've never been able to include a directory at whole because of the dependencies across various scripts...  This might be a way around it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323409/asp-net-mvc-bundle-config-order

Comment: I tried with orderer , still am facing the same issue . while adding angular files to bundle is the issue.