# Include all files in a folder in a single bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

When using `BundleConfig` is it possible to include all files of a folder including all the files of the childfolders (and their childfolders etc.)?

I found `.IncludeDirectory()` but it seems to only include the files of the folder itself, not the files of the subfolders.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

Use the overload of [IncludeDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj646468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which accepts `bool searchSubdirectories` as third parameter.

MSDN:

> searchSubdirectories - Specifies whether to recursively search
>   subdirectories of directoryVirtualPath.

Example:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts", "*.js", true));
```

Comment: can we order the files in the directory as done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11981271/2218697) ?

Comment: this doesn't including `.min` files, is there a solution ? , cause i have `.min` and `.js` files in the folder

Comment: @stom, min files are usually included by the bundles in the release mode.

Comment: yes you are correct as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22515066/2218697) , i have changed the `web.config` to `<compilation debug="false">`  and in `BundleConfig.cs` added `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` thank you.

Comment: @Zabavsky, There is a bug in Web.Optimization version 1.1 in which your answer doesn't work, but updating to the latest version or downgrading to 1.0 will fix it. Might want to add that to your answer to save people some time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612157/asp-net-mvc-5-sub-directory-bundling-issues/22613864#22613864