# ASP.Net MVC 5 sub-directory bundling issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am seeing a weird behavior with bundling in my ASP.Net MVC 5 project. My project works just fine when I explicitly declare all the files in my BundleConfig.cs file as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
                "~/app/app.js",
                "~/app/config.js",
                "~/app/dir1/file1.js",
                "~/app/dir1/subdir1/file2.js",
                .....
```

However, if I switch to use `IncludeDirectory` instead, the script paths during development (`BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false`) are not complete. This is what I see:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app").Include(
                "~/app/app.js",
                "~/app/config.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/app/dir1", "*.js", true)
```

Chrome shows me a 404 when it is trying to get `file2.js`. The bundling system adds the following to my layout page:

```
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/app/config.js"></script>
<script src="/app/dir1/file1.js"></script>
<script src="/app/dir1/file2.js"></script>
```

The path to `file2.js` is wrong. It omits the `subdir1` part of the path. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `It omits the dir2 part of the path`. Do you mean `subdir1`?

Comment: yes - sorry about that. fixed it.

Comment: That's strange behavior. The bundler shouldn't follow directories recursively, so if you include `~/app/dir1`, it should only include files immediately in that directory. If it's also including files in subdirectories, while not actually including that subdirectory in the path, that's a new one on me. In general, your best practice here is to be explicit. If you want a file included, include that file explicitly. Things like `IncludeDirectory` are dangerous in my opinion.

Comment: What I think you *should* see in the browser html source is something like <script src="/bundles/app?v=*randomdigitshere*"></script> are you running the site locally?

Comment: Yeah, I assume the OP is running locally, as the bundler doesn't do anything but just include all the files in debug mode. Regardless, though, even in production, the OP might have just the one file, but the code from `/app/dir1/subdir1/file2.js` would be missing from that bundled file. It doesn't really affect the question or possible answers either way.

Comment: @mortb I am running the site locally and I am in "debug" mode. the randomdigits are only going to show up in "release" mode or if set the following flag:BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a known issue w/ version 1.1.1. Upgrade the package (or downgrade to 1.1.0) and it should fix your problem.

[Web Optimization path issue while in debug mode](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/105)