# Bunding not working in ASP.Net MVC4 while same working in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have ASP.Net MVC4 site.

I am bundling all my css but its not working. But same thing is working in another application using ASP.Net MVC5

This is my folder structure:-

```
>>Styles
    >>Css
       >>Bootstrap_folder>>bootstrap.css
       >>site.css
       >>font.css
```

In my BundleConfig.css

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Styles/Css/cssBundle").Include(
                    "~/Styles/Css/Bootstrap_folder/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Styles/Css/site.css",
                    "~/Styles/Css/fonts.css"
            ));
```

Now when I am running the application, **site.css and font.css are included** but the css files in bootstrap folder or other are not included.

But same thing is rendering fine in ASP.Net MVC5

I am in need that I should be free to include any subfolder files.

Comment: What exact issue you are having  ? have u check page source and network items ?

Comment: I pressed ctrl+u and checked which stylesheets are included and as per that only site.css, font.css included not the files in any other folder..
this is the issue

Comment: It looks like you have to tell it to [include subdirectories](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19894495/3585500). Maybe it Just Works in MVC 5?

Comment: have u published your application or checking in debug mode (in visual studio) ?

Comment: @KaushikThanki
 debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Remove the under score  in Bootstrap_folder. Rename it to Bootstrapfolder

Comment: do you think Bootstrap_folder will be the actual name of the folder.. just a dummy name that I have provided here..however in actual there is no underscore in the folder name..
**having underscore or not doesn't make any difference**

Comment: I recommended removing the underscore because of the potential of white spaces between them which may not translate to the exact filepath or name on your machine. However if you dummy answer is not same as the issues you have then how would anyone know your problem and give you a reasonable answer?