# Using JqGrid with ASP.Net MVC and the proper placement of Jquery link using Bundling

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I'm experimenting with JqGrid in the ASP.Net MVC 5 environment.

It seems that Jquery must be loaded before the code:`@Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.ContactsGrid, "Grid")`

But for best performance Jquery should be bundled and loaded at the end of the page.

Do I have to change this for pages that contain JqGrid?

Comment: The MVC helper just writes js and html for the specific jqgrid table wherever the razor tag is placed. So, if jquery/jqgrid is at the bottom of the page, that block of js for the specific table is attempting  to call jquery/jqgrid functions that haven't loaded. Couldn't the helper be rewritten to render just the html at the placement and add the js to a RenderSection script block? Then call RenderSection("otherscripts") at the bottom of the page after jquery/jqgrid calls?

Answer (score 1):

jqGrid is jQuery plugin and so jQuery have to be loaded of cause before jqGrid. I think that if you would use `<link>` and `<script>` with `src` inside of `<head>` you will have also very good performance because the files will be get typically from the **local cache of the web browser**. If you still prefer to use bundles you can specify **the order** of JavaScripts which will be bundled. You can for example use [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj646482%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of files in the bundle in an explicit order (see [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979718/315935) for more details, [the post](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) and [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451436.aspx)). In the way you will have no problem too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Nuget package for jqgrid which will do it automatically.

Comment: I tried. It does not or at least it did not do it in my case.