# ASP.NET Web Optimization - confusion about loading order

Tags: asp.net, web-optimization

Using the `ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework`, I am attempting to load some javascript files up. It works fine, except I am running into a peculiar situation with either the loading order, the loading speed, or its execution. I cannot figure out which.

Basically, I am using `ace` code editor for javascript, and I also want to include its autocompletion package. This requires two files.

`/ace.js`

`/ext-language_tools.js`

This isn't an issue, if I load both of these files the normal way (with `<script>` tags) it works fine. But when I try to use the web optimization bundles, it seems as if something goes wrong.

Trying this out...

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js") {
   .Include("~/js/ace.js")
   .Include("~/js/ext-language_tools.js")
});
```

and then in the view ..

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/js")
```

I get the error

> ace is not defined

This means that the `ace.js` file hasn't run, or hasn't loaded. Because if I break it apart into two bundles, it starts working.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js") {
   .Include("~/js/ace.js")
});

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/js/language_tools") {
   .Include("~/js/ext-language_tools.js")
});
```

Can anyone explain why this would behave in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is well explained in [MSDN Magazine: Programming CSS: Bundling and Minification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn451436.aspx) (scroll to **More Advanced Bundling Features** section).

An excerpt (I bolded some text):

> In particular, the **BundleCollection** class has a couple of features that are worth mentioning even though they’re mostly useful when script files—rather than CSS files—are bundled.
>
> The first feature is ordering. The BundleCollection class has a property named Orderer of type **IBundleOrderer**. As obvious as it may seem, an orderer is a component responsible for determining the actual order in which you want files to be bundled for download. The default orderer is the **DefaultBundleOrderer** class. This class bundles files in the order that results from the settings set via FileSetOrderList—a property of BundleCollection. The FileSetOrderList is designed to be a collection of BundleFileSetOrdering classes. Each of these classes defines a pattern for files (for example, jquery-*), and the order in which BundleFileSetOrdering classes are added to FileSetOrderList determines the actual order of files. For example, given the default configuration, all jQuery files are always bundled before Modernizr files.

The source for [DefaultBundleOrderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.defaultbundleorderer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class is [here](https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Optimization/DefaultBundleOrderer.cs).

However, of particular interest is the [BundleCollection](https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Optimization/BundleCollection.cs) class' **AddDefaultFileOrderings** function (screenshot below).

[image: BundleCollection]

Now, going back to your question, in your bundle you have `ace.js` and `ext-language_tools.js`. The latter file matches `ext-*` and as a result will always be included at the top of the file list in your bundle before `ace.js`.

**SOLUTION:**

This is already answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11981271/2291748).

The same solution is also given in the MSDN Magazine (link at the top).

Another method described there is to "reset all orderings using the following code":

```
    bundles.ResetAll();
```

"In this case, the effect of using the default orderer or the poor man’s orderer shown earlier is the same. Note, though, that ResetAll also resets script orderings."

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for posting this. It really helped. I know that to the immediate glance, it seems like "Wow, you're stupid. Just use the second bundle and be done with it", but it is more than that. It is a legitimate issue that can have far reaching implications down the line for other things, and it is something that I feel __does__ need to be understood. I do not have an MSDN Magazine subscription, so I would have probably been searching forever for this!

Comment: Hey, I'm glad I could help! I agree it's a tricky feature that probably caught some developers off guard. I'm surprised this is not well documented.

Comment: @async -- It gets even better. All the documentation appears to focused towards the MVC group and critical parts of the documentation do not exist for non-MVC web applications.