# Asp.net MVC 5 bundle all scripts in one file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, bundle

In one of my razor page I have the following in the scripts section

```
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script1")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script2")
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script3")
```

The problem is it will render 3 JavaScript files. Is there any way they can be bundled in one file without changing the BundleConfig file?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is it will render 3 JavaScript files. Is there any way they can be bundled in one file without changing the BundleConfig file?

No, you will have to change your BundleConfig.

> Well, if you want to reuse script1 in another page, how will you do that?

[Make a script bundle include another script bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553164/make-a-script-bundle-include-another-script-bundle/27555257#27555257)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create a Bundle containing all the files from Script1, 2 and 3 Bundles and then lets say if its called ScriptAll bundle then you can render it with 1 line. Unfortunately you will have to change your BundleConfig

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scriptall")
```

Comment: How is this possible *without changing the BundleConfig file?*

Comment: @ErikPhilips I did mention that this is not possible without changing BundleConfig.

Comment: One way is using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/842961/Introducing-Dynamic-Bundles-for-ASP-NET-MVC but I am yet reluctant of adding that library

Answer (score 0):

why would You do this ? copy the code from these 3 files and paste it to one.js file then pass it to bundles.

Comment: Well, if you want to reuse script1 in another page, how will you do that?

Comment: if you want to use your scripts on all views assigned to Your layout You should pass it to BundleConfig , but if Your script file is executed on only one of Your view's You should load it into view by @Scripts.Render section. You don't want to load unnecessary js files to Your Views ;)