# jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My project includes JS files for [JQuery.DataTable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.datatables/) plugin from NuGet. I also have [jQuery 2.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/) referenced in my project.

Though I load jQuery using `<%:Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") %>`, reference jQuery UI + DataTables (which gets translated in a successful `<script>` tag, I get tons of errors in my Firebug console

```
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.AutoFill ) {


dataTab...Fill.js (linea 848, col 20)
TypeError: $.fn.dataTable is undefined


$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {

dataTab...trap.js (riga 2)
TypeError: $.fn.dataTableExt is undefined


$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnColReorder = function ( oSettings, iFrom, iTo )

dataTab...rder.js (riga 110)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.ColVis ) {


dataTab...lVis.js (linea 1100, col 20)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns ) {


dataTab...umns.js (linea 1392, col 20)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.FixedHeader ) {


dataTab...ader.js (linea 1021, col 20)
TypeError: $.fn.dataTable is undefined


$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {

dataTab...tion.js (riga 2)
TypeError: DataTable is undefined


$.extend( true, DataTable.defaults, {

dataTab...ryui.js (riga 9)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.KeyTable ) {


dataTab...able.js (linea 1169, col 20)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.Responsive ) {


dataTab...sive.js (linea 794, col 20)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.Scroller ) {


dataTab...ller.js (linea 1255, col 20)
TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTable is undefined


else if ( jQuery && !jQuery.fn.dataTable.TableTools ) {


dataTab...ools.js (linea 3208, col 20)
```

I have defined the DataTables bundle with

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js").Include("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js")
.IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4", "*.js", false));
```

That gets translated into at least

```
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.autoFill.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.bootstrap.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.colReorder.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.colVis.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.fixedColumns.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.fixedHeader.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.foundation.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.jqueryui.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.keyTable.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.responsive.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.scroller.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/dataTables.tableTools.js">
<script src="/Scripts/DataTables-1.10.4/jquery.dataTables.js">
```

The same happens with [Superfish](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SuperFish/) but let's solve one thing at a time. How can I solve this?

Comment: `jquery.dataTables.js` needs to be loaded first, before the `autofill`,`bootstrap` etc. files. You need to implement `IBundleOrderer`, or include the files in that order manually. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979718/how-can-i-specify-an-explicit-scriptbundle-include-order

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rory's comment above answers this question.

> jquery.dataTables.js needs to be loaded first, before the autofill,bootstrap etc. files. You need to implement IBundleOrderer, or include the files in that order manually. More info here: [How can I specify an explicit ScriptBundle include order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11979718/1080891)

I found simply writing my DataTable bundle like this solved my issues:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatable").Include(
            "~/Scripts/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js",
            "~/Scripts/dataTables/dataTables*"));
```