# Bundle and minification has scripts out of order

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have my scripts and css in bundles

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/initialization").Include(
            "~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CustomEventURLS.js",
            "~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CommonFunctions.js",
            "~/Scripts/Custom/Common/GlobalVariables.js"
            ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
    "~/Scripts/Custom/kendoNotification.js",
    "~/Scripts/Custom/Common/CommonControlsJS.js",
    "~/Scripts/Custom/Reporting/Reporting.js",
    "~/Scripts/Custom/Common/Base64ToBinary.js",
    "~/Scripts/Custom/Plugins/Custom_Plugins.js",
    "~/Scripts/2c_Combined_JS.js",
    "~/Scripts/2c_Administration_JS.js",
    "~/Scripts/Custom/Administration/FirstTimeLogin.js"
    ));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
          "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
          "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

//BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

If I have BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; commented out then everything loads properly, but once I uncomment it out then I start getting errors about it not finding certain functions. So this leads me to believe that when I enable the optimizations to true, that it throws all my scripts out of order.

In the header of my layout page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/initialization")
```

and just before the closing of the body brace is

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom")
```

The reason why the custom is at the bottom is because I need the dom to be loaded before those scripts fire.

If I don't use bundling and minification then everytime the app gets published I have to always do a ctrl+f5 and thats not good.

How can I fix this so that my scripts don't get reordered?

Comment: You can try this one if you want a strict order of loading of your scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979718/how-can-i-specify-an-explicit-scriptbundle-include-order/11981271#11981271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `RegisterBundles` function add the following as the first line:

```
bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
```

Also make sure all your min files are valid files (css and js).

Comment: Just tried and still getting uncaught reference errors on 3 functions plus a Lexical declaration cannot appear in a single-statement context error

Comment: I just fixed the lexical error and with your answer, things are working properly now. No errors

Comment: @Chris good to know it resolved the issue. Hope you don't mind up voting! :)

Answer (score 1):

Review and see the the [Bundling and Minification - ASP.NET MVC Demystified](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-bundling-and-minification/) written by **Matthew Jones** one of my favorite web developer.